# How test component undecorator with @decorator (redux-connect) on AVA?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, ecmascript-next, ava

I'm try test a component undecorator, but I'm not getting.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

@connect(({ user }) => ({ user }))
export class Componente extends Component {
    render () {
        return <div>hello {this.props.user}</div>
    }
}
```

Example test:

```
import test from 'ava'
import Component from './Component'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

test('<Component />', t => {
  let wrapper = mount(<Component />) // the connect's redux create a wrapper component :(
})
```

It is possible to test a component undecorated? How?

Comment: Decorators are a *proposal*, they are not part of ES7.

Answer (score 2):

The wrapper class generated by `connect` exposes the inner component class as a static field named `WrappedComponent`, so you can test it out separately.  See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#static-properties .

Comment: Okay, so can not isolate the component after using @decorator on component?